# If Statement? Don't add numbers into total variable if they are negative

Tags: javascript, if-statement, negative-number

Question, how do I make it so when an user-inputted number is negative, it isn't added to the total variable that will be ouput?

Code below!

```
function lab10logicInLoopsPart1() 
{

lCounter = 1;
var total = 0;
userNumber = 0;

while(lCounter < 6) {
lCounter++;
userNumber = prompt("Enter a number.");
total += +userNumber;
document.write("Entered number was: " + userNumber + "\n");
}
document.write("\nTotal: " + total);
}
```

Comment: Use an `if (userNumber >= 0)`

Comment: Total += max(0,userNumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After prompting the user to enter a number, just check it's not a negative with an if statement:

```
if(userNumber >=0)
{ //do your stuff here}
```

Comment: Ah okay that worked! Wasn't aware you could put IFs inside WHILEs. You'd think the instructor would tell us! Thanks again Jose!